# How to add vim-plugins into git repo?

Tags: git, vim, github, vim-plugin

I created a git repo and add vim-plugins ( which is installed by vundle) into it, after I pushed this repo to github, and clone this repo to another server, I found that vim-plugin's directory is empty, dirs and files under vim-plugin's directory are all missing

How to produce it:

```
$ make a new test user in Linux, then ( su - test )
$ git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git ~/.vim/bundle/vundle # install vundle
$ echo "
  set nocompatible
  filetype off
  set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
  call vundle#rc()
  Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
  Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'
  filetype plugin indent on
  " >> .vimrc
$ vim # run vim command `:BundleInstall`
$ mkdir vimgitrepo && cd vimgitrepo && git init
$ cp -a ~/.vim/bundle .
$ git status
  # On branch master
  # Untracked files:
  #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  #
  #       bundle/
  nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git add .
$ git status
  # On branch master
  # Changes to be committed:
  #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  #
  #       new file:   bundle/vim-powerline
  #       new file:   bundle/vundle
  #
```

As you can see, only directories are added.

```
$ git commit -m'test'
$ git push -u origin master
```

And if you clone this repo on another place, only empty directory exists.

Here is [test vimgitrepo github page](https://github.com/nfpyfzyf/gitvimrepo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You copied the whole directories into your repo, which are other git repos and contains `.git/` directory in them.

So you have two way to solve it:

1. use command [`git submodule`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html), set them as submodules.
2. delete the `.git/` in these directories before your first commit.